# Is it necessary to disown a process for it to continue running after disconnecting?

Tags: ssh, jobs, disown

Would someone explain if & why `disown` is necessary if you wish to keep a job running even after you disconnect.

I ask because every site I have visited says to use `disown` and `bg` but `bg` on its own is working for me and I'm not sure why.

Is it because I haven't fully understood what `disown` is for or are there some settings somewhere that are affecting the default behavior of the `bg` command?

Here's what I did:

- Connected to my CentOS 6 box via SSH
- Created a simple process:

  ```
  tar zcvf example.tar.gz ./examplepath > /dev/null 2>&1
  ```
- Suspended the job
- Resumed it in background via `bg 1`
- Disconnected from SSH server

I then checked via FTP to see if the `.tar.gz` file was still growing in size and it was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Processes backgrounded via `bg` or `&` will typically die under 2 scenarios:

1. The shell receives a SIGHUP
2. They try to write to a terminal which no longer exists.

Item #1 is the primary culprit when closing your terminal. However whether it happens or not depends on **how** you close your terminal. You can close it by:

1. Something like clicking the "X" in your window manager
2. You can type `exit`, `logout`, or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Item #1 is the one that will result in a SIGHUP being sent. #2 does not.

So long story short, if you background a process with `bg`, and then log out with `exit`, `logout`, or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, the process will not be killed.

Comment: Thanks. The `logout` or CTRL+D method not resulting in `SIGHUP` explains everything.

Answer (score 1):

When you close a terminal, all processes that uses this terminal (see `TTY` column in `ps -elf` output) receive a `SIGHUP`. It's up to process what to do on `SIGHUP`. In classic unixes (AIX, Solaris), process are closed on this signal. That's why you need to use `disown`. From `man bash`:

> The shell exits by default upon receipt of a SIGHUP.  Before exiting,
>   an interactive shell resends the SIGHUP to all jobs, running or
>   stopped.  Stopped jobs are sent SIGCONT to ensure  that they  receive 
>   the  SIGHUP.   To  prevent the shell from sending the signal to a
>   particular job, it should be removed from the jobs table with the
>   disown builtin (see SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below) or marked to not
>   receive SIGHUP using disown -h.

Comment: Are you saying the behavior varies by process and in my case, `tar` doesn't close in response to a `SIGHUP` but another process might?